# Is there an efficient function in Rust that finds the index of the first occurrence of a value in a sorted vector?

Tags: rust, slice

In `[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0]`, if the value we are searching for is 1, then the function should return 2.

I found [binary search](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by), but it seems to return the last occurrence.

I do not want a function that iterates over the entire vector and matches one by one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`binary_search` assumes that the elements are sorted in less-to-greater order. Yours is reversed, so you can use [`binary_search_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by):

```
let x = 1; //value to look for
let data = [3,2,1,1,1,0];
let idx = data.binary_search_by(|probe| probe.cmp(x).reverse());
```

Now, as you say, you do not get the first one. That is expected, for the binary search algorithm will select an arbitrary value equal to the one searched. From the docs:

> If there are multiple matches, then any one of the matches could be returned.

That is easily solvable with a loop:

```
let mut idx = data.binary_search_by(|probe| probe.cmp(&x).reverse());
if let Ok(ref mut i) = idx {
   while x > 0 {
       if data[*i - 1] != x {
           break;
       }
       *i -= 1;
   }
}
```

But if you expect many duplicates that may negate the advantages of the binary search.

If that is a problem for you, you can try to be smarter. For example, you can take advantage of this comment in the docs of `binary_search`:

> If the value is not found then `Result::Err` is returned, containing the index where a matching element could be inserted while maintaining sorted order.

So to get the index of the first value with a `1` you look for an imaginary value just between `2` and `1` (remember that your array is reversed), something like `1.5`. That can be done hacking a bit the comparison function:

```
let mut idx = data.binary_search_by(|probe| {
    //the 1s in the slice are greater than the 1 in x
    probe.cmp(&x).reverse().then(std::cmp::Greater)
});
```

There is a handy function [`Ordering::then()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then) that does exactly what we need (the Rust stdlib is amazingly complete).

Or you can use a simpler direct comparison:

```
let idx = data.binary_search_by(|probe| {
    use std::cmp::Ordering::*;
    if *probe > x { Less } else { Greater }
});
```

The only detail left is that this function will always return `Err(i)`, being `i` either the position of the first `1` or the position where the `1` would be if there are none. An extra comparison is necessary so solve this ambiguity:

```
if let Err(i) = idx {
    //beware! i may be 1 past the end of the slice
    if data.get(i) == Some(&x) {
        idx = Ok(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since 1.52.0, `[T]` has the method [`partition_point`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.partition_point) to find the partition point with a predicate in O(log N) time.

In your case, it should be:

```rust
let xs = vec![3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0];
let idx = xs.partition_point(|&a| a > 1);
if idx < xs.len() && xs[idx] == 1 {
    println!("Found first 1 idx: {}", idx);
}
```

Comment: `if xs.get(idx) == Some(&1)` is shorter.